# When do I close TransportClient in Elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I would like to know what is the good practice when opening and closing java elasticsearch client.
Do I open and close it between each request ? Or can I use a single instance of client for all requests ?

```
private Client client;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    try {
        client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(host), port));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Unable to create ESClient : {}", e);
    }
}

@PreDestroy
public void destroy() {
    client.close();
}
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you don't have to close transport client after each request. It will be a too much of an overhead.

See the docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html).

```
// on startup

TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host1"), 9300))
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host2"), 9300));

// on shutdown

client.close();
```

There you can see the comment lines "on startup" and "on shutdown". So basically that tells you when you should call `client.close()`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a single client for all your requests.

Opening a connection is a costly operation and you do not want to open and close one every time you issue a request.

Simply close the client when you end your server or application.

Comment: what if I want to do 10K request/sec? how many sockets will open underneath and when will they get closed given that my REST server almost never ends since it has served the request from clients all the time? I do run into fd max limit issue so if I have an understanding of when sockets get open and closed that would help so I can try and model my solution around it